# performance issue variable assignment

Tags: performance, variable-assignment

I am wondering, what scenario would be best ?

(Please bare with my examples, these are just small examples of the situation in question. I know you could have the exact same function without a result variable.)

**A)**

```
    public String doSomthing(){
       String result;
       if(condition){ result = "Option A";}
       else{ result = "Option B";}
       return result;
   }
```

**B)**

```
   public String doSomthing(){
       String result = "Option B";
       if(condition){ result = " Option A";}
       return result;
   }
```

---

Cause in scenario B: if the condition is met, Then you would be assigning result a value twice. 
Yet in code, i keep seeing scenario A.

Comment: What programming language is this, Java? Please tag your question with it.

Comment: Yes it does. Most languages do have a [sufficiently smart compiler](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SufficientlySmartCompiler) that will produce the same result for both codes.

Comment: Then that is my answer, thx !

Comment: Do you believe that not using a variable at all (`if (condition) return "Option A"; else return "Option B";` or `return condition ? "Option A" : "Option B";`) would have even better performance (apart from the much increased readability)?

Comment: Now that i know of the existance of the so called " Sufficiently smart compiler" i don't.

Comment: No smart compiler should tolerate returning a `String` from a `void` function :)

Comment: haha yea, thx, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the overhead here is minimal, if any, considering the compiler optimisations. You would not care about it in a professional coding environment, unless you are writing a compiler yourself.

What is more important, considering (modern) programming paradigms, is the code style and readability.

Example A is far more readable, as it has a well-presented reason-outcome hierarchy. This is important especially for big methods, as it saves the programmer lots of analysis time.